# How to trigger Ajax with flash buttons?

Tags: ajax, actionscript-3

I'm working on something where there are 2 links which triggers some Ajax. However I need to turn the links into Flash buttons (AS3). I've never worked with Ajax before, and I have no idea how this can be done.

**Edit:**

The Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

          $('a.catlink').unbind('click').click(function(e)
          {

                  e.preventDefault();

                  var link = $(this);
                  var inputs = [];                      

                  var cat_type = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');

                  link.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                  inputs.push('cat_type=' + escape(cat_type));

                  $.ajax(
                   {
                     type: "POST",
                     cache: false,
                     dataType: "html",
                     url: window.location.href,
                     data: inputs.join('&'),
                     success: function(html)
                       {
                          var json = $.parseJSON(html);

                          if (json['status'] == 1)
                          {
                              $('div.listing').html(json['html']);
                          }
                          link.removeAttr('disabled');                            
                       }
                   });
          });
      });
</script>
```

The HTML

```
    <h1 class="section-head">Products  
      // **The 2 links*** //
      <a class="catlink" href="#cinema">cinema</a> <a class="catlink" href="#smart">smart</a></h1>
    <div class="listing">
      <ul class="listing">
          {foreach from=$products item="product_info"}
          <li class="clearfix">
              <div class="inner-left">
                  <a href="{if $product_info.title_url}{$product_info.title_url}{else}{$product_info.url}{/if}"><img height="68" width="90" src="{$product_info.image}" /></a>
                  <h2 class="normal mt-5"><a href="{$product_info.url}">{if $product_info.price != '0'}${$product_info.price}{else}Click for price &raquo;{/if}</a></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="inner-right">
                  <h3 class="mb-0"><a href="{if $product_info.title_url}{$product_info.title_url}{else}{$product_info.url}{/if}">{$product_info.productName}</a></h3>
                  <p class="small mb-5"><span class="quiet">{$product_info.category}</span></p>
                  <p class="mb-15">{$product_info.description}</p>
                  <a class="button getprice" href="{$product_info.url}">Buy Now</a>
                  <br><br>
              </div>
          </li>
          {/foreach}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use AS3 then you can use `ExternalInterface.call()` to call a JavaScript function on the page. Though, using Ajax may not be required if you're using AS3 because you can make use of the `URLLoader` class to do the same thing (call a PHP script and decode a result).

If you describe more accurately what you want to achieve then I shall provide some example code and clarify a little more.

Comment: Cheers, though I'm afraid I can't grasp what you want to do with AS3 exactly?

Comment: Oh right. So instead of those two link there (2nd line in the HTML) that refreshes the products. I need to replace them with 2 flash buttons on top of the page. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Alright so assuming you know how to embed flash onto a webpage, you just need to create a button and use ExternalInterface to call your AJAX. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html